# Story ID: humans in invulnerable powered armor vs telepathic enemy aliens with transporter-based handheld cutting weapon

Tags: story-identification, aliens, weapon, telepathy, military-sf

Military science fiction story, most probably from the 1970's or 1980's, possibly a short story in an anthology, but more likely a novella, or maybe even a full novel.

Small squad of human soldiers in extremely capable environmentally sealed fighting suits; improved version of powered armor suits in Joe Haldeman's "Forever War."

In first contact, non-humanoid enemy aliens use telepathic powers to make themselves appear human; see the Kelvans in the Star Trek TOS episode "By any other name."  They appear as archetypal dominant male and female humans, nude with exaggerated sexual characteristics.

Aliens use a handheld cutting weapon based on "transporter-like" effect that disappears thin slices from any target.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is "[Mindbridge](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1522)" by Joe Haldeman, my favourite of his novels.

Some details filled in by the question author in a comment:

> The improved powered armor is the GPEM "general purpose exploration module." The aliens are the L'vrai. The scene I described in my original question is in 33-Chapter 9.

I answered already here https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/174531/28516 which was closed as a duplicate of the "master" question
https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/67596/28516

Comment: I can't say this isn't the one, but I don't really see anything in the other answers that addresses their points other than that some of the aliens are psychic, let alone this answer supporting it. :)

Comment: Yes, Mindbridge...siting on my bookshelf ignored for 20+ years.  The improved powered armor is the GPEM "general purpose exploration module."  The aliens are the L'vrai.  The scene I described in my original question is in 33-Chapter 9.  Many thanks for the help.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots slam dunk!

Comment: @OrganicMarble: Got to keep you guys honest somehow...